# Unable to get data from dataset (too many values to unpack (expected 2))

Tags: python, image-recognition

The following line is where my image dataset is stored:

```
img_folder = r'/Users/joshu/Desktop/Level 6 Year 2/Semester 2/ITProject/car-segmentation/images/'
```

In the following I'm creating the dataset:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    img_folder,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

In the following function I'm trying to get the data:

```
def get_data():
    # generate dataset
    X, y = train_ds
    # split into train and test
    n_test = 500
    trainX, testX = X[:n_test, :], X[n_test:, :]
    trainy, testy = y[:n_test], y[n_test:]
    return trainX, trainy, testX, testy
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\Level 6 Year 2\Semester 2\ITProject\Git\itproject62b\src\prototype.py", line 63, in <module>
    trainX, trainy, testX, testy = get_data()
  File "C:\Users\joshu\Desktop\Level 6 Year 2\Semester 2\ITProject\Git\itproject62b\src\prototype.py", line 43, in get_data
    X, y = train_ds
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error and the sample data.

Comment: How many subdirectories you have in your ```img_folder```?

Comment: 2 subdirectories

Comment: It seems like your ```train_ds``` is yielding more than 2 values. Try to check the length of the tuple returned.

Comment: It is going in the subdirectories and getting all the images. Even if I give it the previous directory it still goes in all the directories